# How to add Emoji in Windows PC?

Tags: node.js, windows, emoji

## I want to use Emoji in Code Using Windows Computer

### I tried searching for emoji to copy and paste in code not as strings instead as pictures so that I can use them such as

```
The Server is Running at Port 3000 <emoji>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this website
https://www.emojicopy.com/

> You can choose the emoji you want and then copy and paste in your code

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>**.**</kbd> to get this dialog:

[image]